# enzyme mount returns unrendered component without erros

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have the following component wrapped in `react-i18next` and a `mobx-react` provider:

```
import React from "react";
import s from "styled-components";
import { observer, inject } from "mobx-react";
import { translate } from "react-i18next";

@inject("uiStore", "fieldsStore")
@observer
export class HeaderCell extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { t } = this.props;

    return (
      <InputSyle>
        <div className="rootCell" />
      </InputSyle>
    );
  }
}

const InputSyle = s.tr`
  background-color: red;
`;

export default translate()(HeaderCell);
```

I am trying to write a simplet test to assert that the .rootCell div gets rendered:

```
import React from "react";

import { Provider } from "mobx-react";

import Enzyme from "enzyme";
import { mount } from "enzyme";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-15";

import HeaderCell from "./HeaderCell";

import { I18nextProvider } from "react-i18next";
import i18n from "../../../../utils/i18n";

const stores = {
  uiStore: {},
  fieldsStore: {}
};

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe("HeaderCell.js", () => {
  it("renders a single .rootCell div", () => {
    const wrapper = mount(
      <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}>
        <Provider {...stores}>
          <HeaderCell />
        </Provider>
      </I18nextProvider>
    );
    expect(wrapper.find(".rootCell")).toHaveLength(1);
  });
});
```

But instead of the test passing I get the following console output:

> FAIL 
>   src/components/Sidebar/ParcelsGrid/HeaderCell/HeaderCell.test.js   ●
>   HeaderCell.js › renders a single .rootCell div
>
> ```
> expect(received).toHaveLength(length)
>
> Expected value to have length:
>   1
> Received:
>   {"length": 0, Symbol(enzyme.__unrendered__): null, Symbol(enzyme.__renderer__): {"batchedUpdates": [Function
> ```
>
> batchedUpdates], "getNode": [Function getNode], "render": [Function
>   render], "simulateEvent": [Function simulateEvent], "unmount":
>   [Function unmount]}, Symbol(enzyme.**root**): {"length": 1,
>   Symbol(enzyme.**unrendered**): , Symbol(enzyme.**renderer**):
>   [Object], Symbol(enzyme.**root**): [Circular],
>   Symbol(enzyme.**node**): [Object], Symbol(enzyme.**nodes**): [Array],
>   Symbol(enzyme.**options**): [Object]}, Symbol(enzyme.**node**):
>   undefined, Symbol(enzyme.**nodes**): Array [],
>   Symbol(enzyme.**options**): {"adapter": [Object]}}
>       received.length:
>         0
>
> ```
>   at Object.it (src/components/Sidebar/ParcelsGrid/HeaderCell/HeaderCell.test.js:30:39)
>       at new Promise (<anonymous>)
>   at Promise.resolve.then.el (node_modules/p-map/index.js:46:16)
>       at <anonymous>
>   at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
> ```

From the message I am assuming that my component is not getting rendered, but I have no idea why.

I am using `"custom-react-scripts": "^0.2.0"`, `"enzyme": "^3.2.0"`,
    `"enzyme-adapter-react-15": "^1.0.5"`, `"react-i18next": "^6.0.6"`.

I would say that the test code is correct, but not really sure? All the wrappers also seem to be working OK as there are no console errors.

Comment: Pretty sure the issue is wrapping the exported component `export default translate()(HeaderCell);`